# Represent QTabWidget's tab text in Qt StyleSheet file?

Tags: qt4, widget, stylesheet

How can i set the font size of the tab text for a QTabWidget , with Qt's StyleSheet file ?
I just don't know "what" widget is that

```
QTabWidget { font: 10pt; }
```

wasn't helping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's QTabBar.

Have a look at the [Customizing QTabWidget and QTabBar](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/stable/stylesheet-examples.html#customizing-qtabwidget-and-qtabbar) docs for info.

This is how to set its font size:

```
QTabBar::tab { font: 10pt }
```